# PHP with Ajax slow response time

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html-table, response

I'm doing a program that would ask user to search from Mysql table based on `onKeyup`. But it seems that the response time is very slow while I don't have that much of data **~ 2873 records**.

Here is my PHP code :

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['master'])){
    require_once('connect_db.php');
    require_once('output_fns.php');

            <div id="openModal6" class="modalDialog6">
            <div>   
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                <h2><center>Search Item</center></h2>

                <p>
          <table>
        <tr><td>
        <b>Item No. :</b><br />
    //User input and onKeyup
        <input type="text" value="" id="item_s" autofocus required onKeyUp="related_item(document.getElementById('item_s').value,document.getElementById('store_s').value);">
        <td><b>Stor</b><br />

    //User select Store by default usually its first store
        <select name='store_s' id='store_s'>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * from stores_list";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            echo "<option value='{$row['short']}'>{$row['short']}</option>";

            }
            echo "</select>";
        }

        else{
            //No Stores Available
            echo "No Stores Found !";
        }
        ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td align="center" colspan="3">
        //Response Output Here
        <div id="txtHint4">Waiting...</div>
        </td></tr>
        </table>


                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
```

Of course this is a Modal dialogue so it basically opens up when user Click on `|Search Button|` and using `Onclick=`

As for Ajax `get_item.php`

```
    <?php
    require_once('connect_db.php');
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $s=$_GET['s'];

    if($_GET['q']=="---"){
    return true;
    exit();
    }

//Select Result From table where item Like
    $query="SELECT * FROM store_items WHERE item_no LIKE '".$q."%' AND store = '".$s."' ORDER by sub Asc";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<table width=100% height=% align=center border=1 bgcolor=white cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 style='font-size:12px;'>";
        echo "<tr><td align=center><b>Item Number</b><td align=center><b>QTY</b><td align=center><b>Unit Cost</b></td><td align=center><b>Unit Sell</b></td><td align=center><b>Cat</b></td><td align=center><b>Sub</b></td><td align=center><b>Description</b></td><td align=center><b>Store</b></td></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr><td align=center>{$row['item_no']}</td><td align=center>{$row['qty']}<td align=center>{$row['actual_price']}</td><td align=center>{$row['selling_price']}</b></td><td align=center>{$row['cat']}</td><td align=center>{$row['sub']}</td><td align=center>{$row['short']}</td><td align=center>{$row['store']}</td></tr>";

    //End of While loop 
    }


    }
    else{
    echo "<br /><center><font color=red>Sorry Item Number Not Found !</font></center>";
    }

    ?>
```

And finally the Function **related_item**

```
function related_item(str,str2)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint4").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_item.php?q="+str+"&s="+str2,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

What have I done wrong this far? it should fetch data quickly from the table, I don't understand like around 4-5 seconds waiting time to see data coming up inside `<div id='txtHint4'>Response</div>`

Please Note the items are only numbers , example `(001200201000)`

---

UPDATE :
I've checked chrome developer tool network to test out the delay part and it seems the delay goes on `get_item.php` file Here are the results

```
Query             0.36
Stalled           0.5
Request Sent      0.14ms
Waiting (TTFB)    77.555ms
Content Download  3.40s
```

So does it mean that there is something wrong with my PHP file? what other or better way to enhance the code? Its straight forward reading from table. Maybe I'm missing something here

Comment: it's because someone has done and sql injection on your db and now you have 23609035 records

Comment: @e4c5 Can you please clarify more, I'm still new to this.

Comment: one does not use mysql_* functions (unless of course they are looking forward to an sql injection attack).

Comment: As for figuring out what's wrong, look at your chrome developer tool network tab to see where the most time is being spent

Comment: @e4c5 ok i'll check it out and will inform you back, thanks.

Comment: @e4c5 Okay I've updated my question

Comment: it seems the delay is actually in transferring all the data. TTFB indicates that the mysql query executes quickly enough as you guessed.